# Cannot redeclare somethingUnique(), previously declared somethingSimilar()

Tags: php, wordpress

This wp plugin has been used for a while and the same version is working fine on another wp site on the same server. Is there some deep optimization on the server or in php that could lead to this?

> [07-Sep-2022 07:41:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare
> getWooCommerceProductBySku() (previously declared in
> /home/redacted/wp-content/plugins/duellintegration/includes/duell.php:92)
> in
> /home/redacted/wp-content/plugins/duellintegration/includes/duell.php
> on line 256

```
...
91 if (!function_exists('getWooCommerceOrderDetailById')) {
92     function getWooCommerceOrderDetailById($id, $fields = null, $filter = array()) {
...
255 if (!function_exists('getWooCommerceProductBySku')) {
256     function getWooCommerceProductBySku($sku) {
...
```

```
OS:     Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.42.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 9 08:11:18 EST 2020 x86_64
Shell:
PHP binary:     /opt/alt/php74/usr/bin/php
PHP version:    7.4.30
php.ini used:   /opt/alt/php74/etc/php.ini
MySQL binary:   /bin/mysql
MySQL version:  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.38, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
SQL modes:
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:       /redacted
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.6.0

Apache Version  2.4.54
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Maybe you include the given file multiple times?

Comment: The error message does not appear to match the code you have shown. It _says_ that `getWooCommerceProductBySku` was previously declared on ljne 92 - but what you have shown us, does not declare that function on line 92, but a different one, `getWooCommerceOrderDetailById`. Have you checked the code of the file on the system where it does not work, is actually what you think it is?

Comment: CBroe: That's the strange thing. The code lines are copied from the exact same file the interpreter complains about, so it should not be a conflict there at all.

Comment: If this is your custom plugin, then make sure you include the `duell.php` file using `include_once` or `require_once` also make sure you don't have any other backup copy activated on your website.